# Input methods do not work

Tags: ibus, input, input-language, input-method, fcitx

I need to use English, Chinese and Spanish input methods on my computer.

Both the Chinese and Spanish input methods:

- show icon but they do not work
- They currently function exactly the same as default English input method

Chinese:

- No Chinese pinyin candidates are shown.

Spanish:

- tildas and Spanish n do not work either.

Software:

- The same results for fcitx and ibus.

`dpkg --get-selections | grep ibus`:

```
gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64 install
ibus install
ibus-gtk:amd64 install
ibus-gtk3:amd64 install
ibus-libpinyin install
ibus-pinyin install
ibus-sunpinyin install
ibus-table install
libibus-1.0-5:amd64 install
libusageenvironment1 install
libusb-0.1-4:amd64 install
libusb-1.0-0:amd64 install
libusb-1.0-0:i386 install
libusbmuxd2:amd64 install
libusbredirhost1:amd64 install
libusbredirparser1:amd64 install
libustr-1.0-1:amd64 install
```

Comment: To help troubleshoot this, can you open a terminal and `lsb_release`, as well as `dpkg --get-selections | grep ibus`, and update the question to include this info? Thanks

Comment: No LSB modules are available.

Comment: gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64    install
ibus      install
ibus-gtk:amd64     install
ibus-gtk3:amd64     install
ibus-libpinyin     install
ibus-pinyin     install
ibus-sunpinyin     install
ibus-table     install
libibus-1.0-5:amd64    install
libusageenvironment1    install
libusb-0.1-4:amd64    install
libusb-1.0-0:amd64    install
libusb-1.0-0:i386    install
libusbmuxd2:amd64    install
libusbredirhost1:amd64    install
libusbredirparser1:amd64   install
libustr-1.0-1:amd64    install

Comment: Did you enable them in _System Settings -> Text Entry_?

Comment: Thanks, I mean what is the output of `lsb_release -a` for you? Thanks

Comment: This is the output:No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 15.10
Release: 15.10
Codename: wily

Answer (score 2):

Recently I had a problem with spanish input method (suddenly misconfigured). I saw my ~/.xinputrc was created some time ago, configured with "ibus". In this file it suggested the command `im-config`

I solved only excecuting:

```
im-config
```

And I followed choosing 'default' and it worked well. I hope it will help you.

Comment: yeah, this worked, but after relogin, i had to open the browser again to upvote this.